# Keyboard disappears on every key press in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to map key value pairs in react native. The value being editable text entry. The mapped components show up fine, but when I try to edit the TextInput, the keyboard disappears when i type the first letter. Don't know whats causing the problem.

If i just put a TextInput in the parent element, it works absolutely fine but doesn't work when I use the map function.

```
 <View style={styles.main}>
        <View>
            {this._getDetailElements()}
        </View>
 </View>
```

_getDetailElements() function

```
 _getDetailElements = () => {

    return Object.keys(this.state.data).map(elem => (
        <View key={shortid.generate()} style={styles.element}>
                <TextInput
                editable={this.state.editable}
                onChangeText={text => this.setState({seletedText: text})}
                value={this.state.selectedText}
                /> 
        </View>
    )
    );
}
```

Comment: you have used shortid.generate() which will generate new key everytime and hence the component was getting re-rendered.

Answer (score 2):

It's because your key on the map changes everytime it rerenders.
Just use the index of the map iteration as key

```
_getDetailElements = () => {

    return Object.keys(this.state.data).map((elem, index) => (
        <View key={index} style={styles.element}>
                <TextInput
                editable={this.state.editable}
                onChangeText={text => this.setState({seletedText: text})}
                value={this.state.selectedText}
                /> 
        </View>
    )
    );
}
```

Comment: good catch. I hit the same issue and your response was a life saver. thanks

Answer (score 1):

i think you should just change the `value` to `defaultValue` Like this :

```
    <TextInput
        editable={this.state.editable}
        onChangeText={text => this.setState({seletedText: text})}
        defaultValue={this.state.selectedText}
    />
```

Good luck

Comment: Doesn't work. Interestingly if I remove the parent view in the mapping function and just map the **TextInput** it works normally as it should.

Comment: Removing the wrapping View fixed it for me as well... kind of annoying though because now I can't make a single wrapped element that I can re-use.

Comment: @AshishGupta: I also had the same problem and your solution of removing the wrapping View worked. Just trying to figure out why is that so - its go to do with the key param

Comment: I just removed the `flex` property from the wrapping View and worked. So strange...